# The functional equation $f(x) = qx + qxf(x) - f(x^2)$

Tags: generating-functions, functional-equations, combinatorics-on-words

A word (i.e., ordered string of letters) is *bifix-free* provided it has no proper initial string and terminal string that are identical. For example, the word $ingratiating$ has bifix $ing$, but the word $ingratiate$ is bifix-free.

Let $a_n^{(q)}$ be the number of bifix-free words over a fixed $q$-letter alphabet. The generating function $f(x) = f^{(q)}(x) = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} a_nx^n$ satisfies the functional equation
$$f(x) = qx + qxf(x) - f(x^2).$$

Solving for $f(x)$ gives
$$f(x) = \frac{qx - f(x^2)}{1-qx} = \cdots = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^jqx^{2^j}}{\prod_{k=0}^{j} (1 - qx^{2^k})}.$$

**(Q1)** Is there a "nice" solution to this functional equation, perhaps one that does not involve an infinite product or sum?

Here is a plot of $f^{(2)}(x)$ generated in Sage:

[image]

The limit as $n \to \infty$ of the probability that a uniformly random word of length $n$ is bifix-free is $1 - f^{(q)}(q^{-2})$. From the initial three terms in the alternating series above, as $q \to \infty$,
$$f^{(q)}(q^{-2}) = \frac{1}{q-1} - \frac{1+o(1)}{q^3}.$$

**(Q2)** What else can be said specifically about $f^{(q)}(q^{-2})$ for integers $q \geq 2$? Is there a simpler formula than the infinite series above? Are these values rational? ...algebraic?

Here is a plot of $f^{(x)}(x^{-2})$ generated in Sage:

[image]

(The combinatorics-on-words paper associated with this function is [here](http://dmtcs.episciences.org/1414).)

Comment: Something interesting I noticed: there's an easy way to get $f_q(x)$ from any other $f_q(x)$, by scaling $x$ by $q$. As such, you only need to care about $f_1(x)$.

Comment: Also, as such, any information about $f_q(q^{-2}) = f(\frac{1}{q})$, so any information about that probability is equivalent to information about your original function itself.

Comment: @user44191 The numerator in the summation has $q\cdot x^{2^j}$ not $(qx)^{2^j}$.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I made a mistake when trying to deal with $f(x^2)$.

Comment: It might be nice for you to provide a table of values of $a_n^{(q)}$ for small values of $n$ and $q$.

Comment: $a_n = a_n^{(q)}$ satisfies the following recursion:
 \begin{eqnarray*}
  a_0 & = & 0;\\
  a_1 & = & q;\\
  a_{2k} & = & qa_{2k-1} - a_k;\\
  a_{2k+1} & = & qa_{2k}.
 \end{eqnarray*}